# libc-bin dpkg segmentation fault

Tags: apt, dpkg, segmentation-fault

In an `apt-get upgrade` i got stuck in this situation where libc-bin constantly provides `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I tried several apt commands such as clean, dpkg-reconfigure and --reinstall but i had no luck.

this is the output of a `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
andrea@andrea-pc: ~ $ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/nvidia-375' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib32/nvidia-375' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.23.so
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.23.so
    libssl.so.1.0.0 -> libssl.so.1.0.0
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.23.so
    libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.23.so
    libjson-c.so.2 -> libjson-c.so.2.0.0
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.23.so
    libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
    libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.4
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.23.so
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.23.so
    libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.2
    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.23.so
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.23.so
    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.23.so
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
    liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
    libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
    libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.2
    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.23.so
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.23.so
    libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.54.0
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.23.so
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.23.so
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.23.so
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.23.so
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.23.so
    libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.24
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.23.so
    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
    libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
    libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.14.0
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
    libjbig.so.0 -> libjbig.so.0
    libgd.so.3 -> libgd.so.3.0.0
    libICE.so.6 -> libICE.so.6.3.0
    libglapi.so.0 -> libglapi.so.0.0.0
    libdrm_intel.so.1 -> libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
    libtiff.so.5 -> libtiff.so.5.2.4
    libgstsdp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstsdp-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libvorbis.so.0 -> libvorbis.so.0.4.8
    libXdmcp.so.6 -> libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
    libxcb-present.so.0 -> libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
    libgpm.so.2 -> libgpm.so.2
    libffi.so.6 -> libffi.so.6.0.4
    libpango-1.0.so.0 -> libpango-1.0.so.0.3800.1
    libicui18n.so.55 -> libicui18n.so.55.1
    libgstapp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstapp-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libXcursor.so.1 -> libXcursor.so.1.0.2
    libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0
    libvorbisenc.so.2 -> libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
    libLLVM-3.8.so.1 -> libLLVM-3.8.so.1
    libpulse.so.0 -> libpulse.so.0.19.0
    libXpm.so.4 -> libXpm.so.4.11.0
    libasyncns.so.0 -> libasyncns.so.0.3.1
    libXxf86vm.so.1 -> libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
    liborc-0.4.so.0 -> liborc-0.4.so.0.25.0
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 -> libgthread-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libcups.so.2 -> libcups.so.2
    libxcb.so.1 -> libxcb.so.1.1.0
    libQtOpenGL.so.4 -> libQtOpenGL.so.4.8.7
    libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
    libXt.so.6 -> libXt.so.6.0.0
    libxshmfence.so.1 -> libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
    libfreetype.so.6 -> libfreetype.so.6.12.1
    liborc-test-0.4.so.0 -> liborc-test-0.4.so.0.25.0
    libdrm.so.2 -> libdrm.so.2.4.0
    libxcb-sync.so.1 -> libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
    libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0 -> libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
    libgstallocators-1.0.so.0 -> libgstallocators-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libaudio.so.2 -> libaudio.so.2.4
    libxslt.so.1 -> libxslt.so.1.1.28
    libgstnet-1.0.so.0 -> libgstnet-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libkrb5.so.26 -> libkrb5.so.26.0.0
    libQtWebKit.so.4 -> libQtWebKit.so.4.10.2
    libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0.3200.2
    libxcb-glx.so.0 -> libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
    libroken.so.18 -> libroken.so.18.1.0
    libdrm_amdgpu.so.1 -> libdrm_amdgpu.so.1.0.0
    libxml2.so.2 -> libxml2.so.2.9.3
    libp11-kit.so.0 -> libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
    libsamplerate.so.0 -> libsamplerate.so.0.1.8
    libXfixes.so.3 -> libXfixes.so.3.1.0
    libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21
    libidn.so.11 -> libidn.so.11.6.15
    libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.375.39
    libgif.so.7 -> libgif.so.7.0.0
    libicule.so.55 -> libicule.so.55.1
    libmenu.so.5 -> libmenu.so.5.9
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 -> libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
    libgmp.so.10 -> libgmp.so.10.3.0
    libdb-5.3.so -> libdb-5.3.so
    libjpeg.so.8 -> libjpeg.so.8.0.2
    libQtXmlPatterns.so.4 -> libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8.7
    libelf.so.1 -> libelf-0.165.so
    libXi.so.6 -> libXi.so.6.1.0
    libvisual-0.4.so.0 -> libvisual-0.4.so.0.0.0
    libkrb5support.so.0 -> libkrb5support.so.0.1
    libFLAC.so.8 -> libFLAC.so.8.3.0
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 -> libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
    libform.so.5 -> libform.so.5.9
    liblber-2.4.so.2 -> liblber-2.4.so.2.10.5
    libharfbuzz.so.0 -> libharfbuzz.so.0.10000.1
    libavahi-client.so.3 -> libavahi-client.so.3.2.9
    libQtCore.so.4 -> libQtCore.so.4.8.7
    libgio-2.0.so.0 -> libgio-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 -> libgstaudio-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libwine.so.1 -> libwine.so.1.0
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 -> libgmodule-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libgssapi.so.3 -> libgssapi.so.3.0.0
    libiculx.so.55 -> libiculx.so.55.1
    libXv.so.1 -> libXv.so.1.0.0
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 -> libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.3800.1
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.30
    libpixman-1.so.0 -> libpixman-1.so.0.33.6
    libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 -> libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3200.2
    libthai.so.0 -> libthai.so.0.2.4
    libQtScript.so.4 -> libQtScript.so.4.8.7
    libcdda_paranoia.so.0 -> libcdda_paranoia.so.0.10.2
    libsasl2.so.2 -> libsasl2.so.2.0.25
    libX11.so.6 -> libX11.so.6.3.0
    libv4l2.so.0 -> libv4l2.so.0.0.0
    libicuio.so.55 -> libicuio.so.55.1
    libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 -> libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libpciaccess.so.0 -> libpciaccess.so.0.11.1
    libtasn1.so.6 -> libtasn1.so.6.5.1
    libasound.so.2 -> libasound.so.2.0.0
    libexif.so.12 -> libexif.so.12.3.3
    libgstrtp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstrtp-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libjacknet.so.0 -> libjacknet.so.0.1.0
    libtic.so.5 -> libtic.so.5.9
    libgsttag-1.0.so.0 -> libgsttag-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libXinerama.so.1 -> libXinerama.so.1.0.0
    libicuuc.so.55 -> libicuuc.so.55.1
    libXss.so.1 -> libXss.so.1.0.0
    libdatrie.so.1 -> libdatrie.so.1.3.3
    libasn1.so.8 -> libasn1.so.8.0.0
    libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0 -> libgstrtsp-1.0.so.0.803.0
    liblcms2.so.2 -> liblcms2.so.2.0.6
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 -> libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
    libkrb5.so.3 -> libkrb5.so.3.3
    libcairo.so.2 -> libcairo.so.2.11400.6
    libgstbase-1.0.so.0 -> libgstbase-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libSM.so.6 -> libSM.so.6.0.1
    libXcomposite.so.1 -> libXcomposite.so.1.0.0
    libQtDeclarative.so.4 -> libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.7
    libmng.so.2 -> libmng.so.2.0.2
    libXrender.so.1 -> libXrender.so.1.3.0
    libieee1284.so.3 -> libieee1284.so.3.2.2
    libsqlite3.so.0 -> libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
    libcapi20.so.3 -> libcapi20.so.3.0.6
    libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
    libfontconfig.so.1 -> libfontconfig.so.1.9.0
    libQtCLucene.so.4 -> libQtCLucene.so.4.8.7
    libmysqlclient.so.20 -> libmysqlclient.so.20.3.4
    libXdamage.so.1 -> libXdamage.so.1.1.0
    libheimntlm.so.0 -> libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
    libltdl.so.7 -> libltdl.so.7.3.1
    libpanel.so.5 -> libpanel.so.5.9
    libopus.so.0 -> libopus.so.0.5.2
    libQtDBus.so.4 -> libQtDBus.so.4.8.7
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 -> libgobject-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 -> libgstvideo-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libspeexdsp.so.1 -> libspeexdsp.so.1.5.0
    libatk-1.0.so.0 -> libatk-1.0.so.0.21809.1
    libX11-xcb.so.1 -> libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
    libsane.so.1 -> libsane.so.1.0.25
    libQtNetwork.so.4 -> libQtNetwork.so.4.8.7
    libogg.so.0 -> libogg.so.0.8.2
    libtheora.so.0 -> libtheora.so.0.3.10
    libexpatw.so.1 -> libexpatw.so.1.6.0
    libxcb-render.so.0 -> libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
    libsndfile.so.1 -> libsndfile.so.1.0.25
    libnettle.so.6 -> libnettle.so.6.2
    libv4lconvert.so.0 -> libv4lconvert.so.0.0.0
    libwind.so.0 -> libwind.so.0.0.0
    libk5crypto.so.3 -> libk5crypto.so.3.1
    libgstcheck-1.0.so.0 -> libgstcheck-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 -> libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.3800.1
    libheimbase.so.1 -> libheimbase.so.1.0.0
    libgstfft-1.0.so.0 -> libgstfft-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libhcrypto.so.4 -> libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.5
    libdrm_nouveau.so.2 -> libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
    libexslt.so.0 -> libexslt.so.0.8.17
    libgstriff-1.0.so.0 -> libgstriff-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libvpx.so.3 -> libvpx.so.3.0.0
    libicudata.so.55 -> libicudata.so.55.1
    libtheoraenc.so.1 -> libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2
    libicutest.so.55 -> libicutest.so.55.1
    libgphoto2_port.so.12 -> libgphoto2_port.so.12.0.0
    libQtGui.so.4 -> libQtGui.so.4.8.7
    libpcreposix.so.3 -> libpcreposix.so.3.13.2
    libXrandr.so.2 -> libXrandr.so.2.2.0
    libgstcontroller-1.0.so.0 -> libgstcontroller-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libhogweed.so.4 -> libhogweed.so.4.2
    libOSMesa.so.8 -> libOSMesa.so.8.0.0
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 -> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.30
    libedit.so.2 -> libedit.so.2.0.53
    libdrm_radeon.so.1 -> libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
    libjack.so.0 -> libjack.so.0.1.0
    libavahi-common.so.3 -> libavahi-common.so.3.5.3
    libgnutls.so.30 -> libgnutls.so.30.6.2
    libgraphite2.so.3 -> libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
    libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
    libtheoradec.so.1 -> libtheoradec.so.1.1.4
    libxcb-shm.so.0 -> libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
    libcdda_interface.so.0 -> libcdda_interface.so.0.10.2
    libXau.so.6 -> libXau.so.6.0.0
    libv4l1.so.0 -> libv4l1.so.0.0.0
    libnvidia-opencl.so.1 -> libnvidia-opencl.so.375.39
    libQtXml.so.4 -> libQtXml.so.4.8.7
    libicutu.so.55 -> libicutu.so.55.1
    libQtSql.so.4 -> libQtSql.so.4.8.7
    libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 -> libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0.803.0
    libhx509.so.5 -> libhx509.so.5.0.0
    libgphoto2.so.6 -> libgphoto2.so.6.0.0
    libopenal.so.1 -> libopenal.so.1.16.0
    libpulse-simple.so.0 -> libpulse-simple.so.0.1.0
    libmpg123.so.0 -> libmpg123.so.0.41.2
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
    libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
    libnss_myhostname.so.2 -> libnss_myhostname.so.2
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.23.so
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.23.so
    libnss_mdns.so.2 -> libnss_mdns.so.2
    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
    libip6tc.so.0 -> libip6tc.so.0.1.0
    libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2
    libiptc.so.0 -> libiptc.so.0.0.0
    libply-splash-graphics.so.4 -> libply-splash-graphics.so.4.0.0
    libssl.so.1.0.0 -> libssl.so.1.0.0
    libx86.so.1 -> libx86.so.1
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
    libnewt.so.0.52 -> libnewt.so.0.52.18
    libseccomp.so.2 -> libseccomp.so.2.3.1
    libpci.so.3 -> libpci.so.3.3.1
    libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
    libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
    libaudit.so.1 -> libaudit.so.1.0.0
    libply-boot-client.so.4 -> libply-boot-client.so.4.0.0
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.23.so
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.23.so
    libjson-c.so.2 -> libjson-c.so.2.0.0
    libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.3.0
    liblzo2.so.2 -> liblzo2.so.2.0.0
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    libisc-export.so.160 -> libisc-export.so.160.0.0
    libnss_mdns6.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6.so.2
    libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.3.0
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.1
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.23.so
    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
    libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.0.5
    libsmartcols.so.1 -> libsmartcols.so.1.1.0
    libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.4
    libntfs-3g.so.861 -> libntfs-3g.so.861.0.0
    libiw.so.30 -> libiw.so.30
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.23.so
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.23.so
    libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.4
    libatm.so.1 -> libatm.so.1.0.0
    libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0
    libnl-genl-3.so.200 -> libnl-genl-3.so.200.22.0
    libapparmor.so.1 -> libapparmor.so.1.4.0
    libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.2
    libip4tc.so.0 -> libip4tc.so.0.1.0
    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.17.0
    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.23.so
    libaio.so.1 -> libaio.so.1.0.1
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.23.so
    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
    libdns-export.so.162 -> libdns-export.so.162.1.3
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.23.so
    libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.6.0
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
    libxtables.so.11 -> libxtables.so.11.0.0
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
    libfdisk.so.1 -> libfdisk.so.1.1.0
    liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
    libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
    libply.so.4 -> libply.so.4.0.0
    libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
    libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.2
    libnih-dbus.so.1 -> libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.23.so
    libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.22.0
    libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
    libbrlapi.so.0.6 -> libbrlapi.so.0.6.4
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    libpcsclite.so.1 -> libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
    libply-splash-core.so.4 -> libply-splash-core.so.4.0.0
    libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.3
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.23.so
    libpng12.so.0 -> libpng12.so.0.54.0
    libprocps.so.4 -> libprocps.so.4.0.0
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libmnl.so.0 -> libmnl.so.0.1.0
    libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.23.so
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.23.so
    libhistory.so.6 -> libhistory.so.6.3
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.23.so
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.23.so
    libparted.so.2 -> libparted.so.2.0.1
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libatasmart.so.4 -> libatasmart.so.4.0.5
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.23.so
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.23.so
    libusb-0.1.so.4 -> libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
    libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.24
    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.23.so
    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.14.6
    libnss_mdns4.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4.so.2
    libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.0
    libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.14.0
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
    libmvec.so.1 -> libmvec-2.23.so
    libulockmgr.so.1 -> libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
```

Answer (score 2):

After debugging with strace I found out that the problem was libtic.so.5.9

I then

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtic.so.5.9 /root
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libtinfo5 --reinstall
```

The latter is to restore libtic :)

Not sure why but now it works.

Comment: Can you throw some light on this similar question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/975318/segmentation-fault-error-processing-package-libc-bin strace log is also attached.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following to find which library that made ldconfig crash:

```
sudo strace ldconfig
```

Then I moved it to /root and reran ldconfig. When ldconfig no longer crashed, the upgrade also worked.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **:-)** It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here: is this a new question?  Then just click [Ask a new question](/questions/ask).  **:-)** If this is a comment to let others know it works, there's no need to do that: once you get a bit more reputation you'll be allowed to [upvote](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) questions.  **:-)** If this is something else entirely please [edit] the answer and elaborate a bit otherwise the system will delete this answer automatically for being unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I just got the same problem while updating a ubuntu 16.04 and fixed it with a variant of the suggested soliuton here, which I want to share:

Removing and reinstalling libtic didn't work for me and using the suggested strace approach, I found the last file opened before core dump was `/var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache`. After removing this file, ldconfig was able to run again.

Final lines of `strace ldconfig --verbose`:

```
open("/var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=65589, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 65589, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fdd26708000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
gettid()                                = 6135
tgkill(6135, 6135, SIGABRT)             = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=6135, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
```

First occurance of problem while apt did an update:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-171.200_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-171.200) over (4.4.0-170.199) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.23) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
```