# apt-get - Segmentation fault: Error Processing package libc-bin

Tags: apt, package-management, libraries, segmentation-fault

Hi I am struggling with this for the past one month.

`sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` is erroring out with following error

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I am running `sudo apt-get install -f`, it is erroring out as follows.

```
Fetched 30.2 MB in 32s (928 kB/s)                                              
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Segmentation fault
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/local/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

1) The question is posted here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907012/segmentation-fault-dpkg-error-processing-package-libc-bin-configure) . But the answer mentioned is specific to the user.

2) As mentioned here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804997/dpkg-error-processing-package-libc-bin-configure), I tried `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc-bin`. But this is showing

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

3) `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  errors out as follows

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libosmesa6:i386
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libglapi-mesa:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 libegl1-mesa:amd64
 xserver-xephyr
 xserver-xorg-core
 libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64
```

Any help will be highly appreciated as this is a machine where all my academic projects are configured, so cannot afford a reinstall.

**EDIT:**

4) `sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 libc-bin` gives the following output:

```
D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: process queue pkg libc-bin:amd64 queue.len 0 progress 1, try 1
D000040: checking dependencies of libc-bin:amd64 (- <none>)
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libc6
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libc6:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libc6
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libc6:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000040: ok 2 msgs >><<
D000040:     checking Breaks
D000400:       checking breaker locales:all virtbroken <none>
Setting up libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.postinst ( configure 2.23-0ubuntu9 )
Segmentation fault
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/local/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
```

**EDIT:**

5) I was trying the solution mentioned here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909459/libc-bin-dpkg-segmentation-fault). But `sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtic.so.5.9 /root` gives the error

```
mv: cannot stat '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtic.so.5.9': No such file or directory
```

Does that mean that in my case some other library is causing the issue?

**EDIT** : I was able to do an strace during `sudo apt-get install -f` and the log is available [here](https://paste.ee/p/QNyyo) ; if that helps anyone.

6) I tried to increase the APT cache limit as mentioned [here](https://aziest.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/how-to-increase-your-apt-cache-limit/). But it did not help.

**EDIT** : **Update** 
Answer to Elder Geek's suggestions

7) I have tested my ram with memtest and it doesn't show any error. I have also conducted a SMART self test on my hard drive (short), which is showing that the "Disk is ok".

8) I have manually checked and this particular library `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtic.so.5.9` does not exist in the location. (So I believe that such a library is not existing in my system and some other library is causing the issue.)

9) I do not have the path `/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu` in my system.

10) There was a Typo, I was checking `/etc/apt/sources.lst` as mentioned in the original answer. I do have a `sources.list` .

These are the entries I can see there. I dont see any ppa mentioned there.

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe
```

Also I am unable to install any ppa manager since apt itself is broken and I am not able to install anything.

11) Additional info : This was originally a 14.04 system which was upgraded to 16.04. Those ppas I had in 14.04 were disabled during the upgrade. However, this upgrade happened almost a year ago and the system was running smoothly for almost an year now.

12) Last and most important: I remember performing a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` some time before all the problems started to appear. Can this be something which caused the issue?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 libc-bin` in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: @dessert edited as requested.

Comment: Please try the solution presented here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/909459/libc-bin-dpkg-segmentation-fault

Comment: Maybe related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1445436

Comment: Please always add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) rather than using comments.

Comment: If think this line should to into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` as explained e.g. [here](https://aziest.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/how-to-increase-your-apt-cache-limit/).

Comment: can you please provide the content of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.postinst` and maybe even for the rest of them in that directory beginning with libc-bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While segmentation faults are normally associated with poorly written code attempting to access a restricted area of memory, I don't believe that's the cause of your issue. While it's not as common these faults can also be caused by misbehaving hardware. I would begin by ensuring that you have a stable environment by running [memtest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833937/execute-memtest86-on-a-ubuntu-16-system) on your system and ensuring that your [hdd is in good shape](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek) if you are using swap. If you discover faulty hardware, replace it.

> Can't stat

means that the file or directory either doesn't exist or your user doesn't have access to it even via sudo. You can check permissions via the `ls -l /lib/i686-linux-gnu` command. Since there is no `/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu` that I can find in a 64-bit version of Ubuntu (assumed based on `Path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu given more than once` ).

My best assessment based on the information you've provided is that the root cause to several of these errors is improper entries in your software sources. These are found in the `/etc/apt/sources.lst` file or the lists in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. You might begin trying to clean it up with [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

If you are running a desktop with GUI, you might prefer [Y PPA Manager](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager) which is a helpful tool for such tasks.

If there's anything confusing or unclear about this answer, please leave a comment and I'll do my best to clarify.

**EDIT:** Further assessment to cover additional points raised since this answer was originally written.

7) In the absence of faulty hardware we'll need to dig a bit deeper

8) abundantly clear since point 5.

9) Also clear since point 4.

**Re-EDIT**10) having a valid /etc/apt/sources.list means you don't need to replace it.

11) I have a system which was also upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, my /etc/apt/sources.list is still intact as you now report your is.

12) That appears possible based on [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1445436) mentioned by dessert in [this comment.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975318/apt-get-segmentation-fault-error-processing-package-libc-bin/979935?noredirect=1#comment1564497_975318)

At this point, the options are limited. Here they are in no particular order. Feel free to pick the one that seems least painful.

1) Revert to a [previous backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

2) Backup user data (you should be doing this anyway) and [install from scratch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

3) Fix your installation. Download [apt](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt) **and all it's dependencies** and reinstall them all with `dpkg -i packagename`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and I have updated points 7 to 12 as per your answer.

Comment: @Erdnase updated answer

Comment: Just one typo spoiled our time. Updated point no 10. Will take the next options once you have a look on it. Thanks.

Comment: @Erdnase It didn't spoil much. Your options aren't really changed, just slightly simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and solve with help of a Brazilian fellow ( https://www.it-swarm.dev/pt/apt/dpkg-pacote-de-processamento-de-erros-libc-bin-configure/961032617/ )

Basically:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/ldconfig/aux-cache
```

end then...

```
/sbin/ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc-bin
sudo dpkg --purge libc-bin
sudo apt install libc-bin
sudo mv /tmp/libc-bin.* /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Source:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/installed+libc-bin+package+post-installation+script+subprocess+returned+error+exit+status+134