# ldconfig: libc-bin dpkg segmentation fault

Tags: dpkg, libraries

I've the same issue as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909459/libc-bin-dpkg-segmentation-fault), but creating a new question since the mentioned is quite old and a further question there is still unanswered. Sorry if this is wrong.

Cite:
*In an apt-get upgrade i got stuck in this situation where libc-bin constantly provides Segmentation fault (core dumped)*

This is the output of *dpkg --configure*.

```
me@foo:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for me:
Setting up libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.4) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
        libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/usr/local/lib:
        libprotoc.so.17 -> libprotoc.so.17.0.0
        libprotobuf.so.17 -> libprotobuf.so.17.0.0
        libprotobuf-lite.so.17 -> libprotobuf-lite.so.17.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
        libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
        libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
        libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
        libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.27.so
        libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
        libulockmgr.so.1 -> libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
        libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.9
        libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
        libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
        libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.21.0
        libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
        libsmartcols.so.1 -> libsmartcols.so.1.1.0
        libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.3.1
        libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1
        libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
        libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
        libseccomp.so.2 -> libseccomp.so.2.5.1
        librt.so.1 -> librt-2.27.so
        libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.27.so
        libreadline.so.7 -> libreadline.so.7.0
        libreadline.so.5 -> libreadline.so.5.2
        libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.27.so
        libprocps.so.6 -> libprocps.so.6.0.0
        libply.so.4 -> libply.so.4.0.0
        libply-splash-graphics.so.4 -> libply-splash-graphics.so.4.0.0
        libply-splash-core.so.4 -> libply-splash-core.so.4.0.0
        libply-boot-client.so.4 -> libply-boot-client.so.4.0.0
        libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.3
        libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
        libpci.so.3 -> libpci.so.3.5.2
        libparted.so.2 -> libparted.so.2.0.1
        libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
        libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
        libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.1
        libntfs-3g.so.88 -> libntfs-3g.so.88.0.0
        libnss_systemd.so.2 -> libnss_systemd.so.2
        libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.27.so
        libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.27.so
        libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.27.so
        libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.27.so
        libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.27.so
        libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.27.so
        libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.27.so
        libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.24.0
        libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0
        libnewt.so.0.52 -> libnewt.so.0.52.20
        libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
        libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
        libmvec.so.1 -> libmvec-2.27.so
        libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0
        libmnl.so.0 -> libmnl.so.0.2.0
        libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
        libm.so.6 -> libm-2.27.so
        liblzo2.so.2 -> liblzo2.so.2.0.0
        liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.2.2
        liblvm2cmd.so.2.02 -> liblvm2cmd.so.2.02
        liblvm2app.so.2.2 -> liblvm2app.so.2.2
        libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.3.2
        libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
        libjson-c.so.3 -> libjson-c.so.3.0.1
        libisns-nocrypto.so.0 -> libisns-nocrypto.so.0
        libisc-export.so.169 -> libisc-export.so.169.0.1
        libidn.so.11 -> libidn.so.11.6.16
        libhistory.so.7 -> libhistory.so.7.0
        libhistory.so.5 -> libhistory.so.5.2
        libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.22.0
        libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.2.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
        libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.7
        libfdisk.so.1 -> libfdisk.so.1.1.0
        libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
        libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.7
        libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
        libdns-export.so.1100 -> libdns-export.so.1100.1.1
        libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.27.so
        libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
        libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1
        libdevmapper-event-lvm2.so.2.02 -> libdevmapper-event-lvm2.so.2.02
        libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.19.4
        libcryptsetup.so.12 -> libcryptsetup.so.12.2.0
        libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.27.so
        libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
        libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.27.so
        libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.25
        libcap-ng.so.0 -> libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
        libc.so.6 -> libc-2.27.so
        libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
        libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.7
        libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.27.so
        libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
        libaudit.so.1 -> libaudit.so.1.0.0
        libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
        libatm.so.1 -> libatm.so.1.0.0
        libapparmor.so.1 -> libapparmor.so.1.4.2
        libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.27.so
        libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.27.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
```

The output of *strace ldconfig* ends with:

```
lstat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdw.so.1", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=14, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdw.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=310656, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 310656, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0x7f2a510fa000
munmap(0x7f2a510fa000, 310656)          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
getpid()                                = 73
gettid()                                = 73
tgkill(73, 73, SIGABRT)                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=73, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Some month ago, I've installed protobuf manually as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072683/how-can-i-install-protoc-on-ubuntu-16-04). The issue occurred suddenly some days ago.

What's going wrong?